# Running a Python function in BASH

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I usually run Python on Google Colab, however I need to run a script in the terminal in Ubuntu.

I have the following script
test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# testing a func

def hello(x):
  if x > 5:
    return "good"
  else:
    return "bad"

hello(2)
```

When executed it fails to return anything. Now I could just replace the return statements with a print statement. However, for other scripts I have, a return statement is needed.

I tried:

```
python test.py
```

You see, on Google Colab, I can simply call the function (hello(2)) and it will execute.

Desired output:

```
> python test.py
> bad
```

Comment: In Unix (or MacOS or Windows), a child process can't **return** anything to the parent process (except an exit code, if you count this as return value). Therefore, a program (this includes Python programs) can not return a string. They can **print** a string to stdout, of course, but you have to tell them to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't print anything to `STDOUT` so you won't see the `good`/`bad` in your terminal.

You should change `hello(2)` line to `print(hello(2))` in your code (In this case the return value of `hello(2)` function call will be printed to `STDOUT` file descriptor) then you will see your result in your terminal.

Comment: Just a note that OP should probably also return proper exit code (be it `0` for "good" and non-zero for "bad")

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to sent the argument when calling the script you could do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def hello(x):
    if x > 5:
        return "good"
    else:
        return "bad"

 print(hello(int(sys.argv[1])))
```

And so you could call the function like so:

```
python test.py 6
```

Then the output would be:

```
> python test.py 6
> good
```